# How to call Session_End when a browser is closed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two questions. I will split my questions into two sections and give an overview. I'm not entirely sure of the code I need to post so if I have missed some out, please let me know and I will help.

Overview:

When the browser is closed I need to sign the user out.

Question 1:

How do I call Session_End when the browser is closed?

I did some reading on how to close it and it seems that the only way to detect if a Session has ended when a browser has been ended is by using something called 'InProc' in my web config. I gave it an attempt and it didn't seem to change anything at all. So I'm wondering if there is another way around this.

Session_End:

```
 protected void Session_End() {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {

            }
        }
```

Question 2: How to sign a user out on Session_End?

Once the program has called the void I need to sign the user out as it's causing a bug in my program. I am using the Authentification manager.

Session_End:

```
protected void Session_End() {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23633068/3919130 Does this help?

Comment: @PrinceTyke Thanks, but not particularly

Answer (score 2):

Using InProc sessions, the Session_End method is called when the session times out. This is (by default) 20 minutes *after* the user has last accessed your site (requested a new page). Note that these 20 minutes could have been spent carefuly reading a single page of your site - his session is still closed.

There is *no* way to detect when a user has closed his browser or navigated away from your site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Global.asax file. It should already contain this Method, all you need to do is add the guts of your code.

```
protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but Session_End is still not called when the browser is closed. Apparently you cannot detect when a browser is closed and run the code anyway